# Find two numbers in array such that they add up to a given a number

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance

The easy way to do this would be a for loop nested inside another.

But I want to solve it this way "check if the array includes both desiredSum-x and x"

```
let givenArray = [1, 2, 5, 4, 4];
let desiredSum = 7;

// nested for loop

// for (i = 0; i < givenArray.length; i++) {
//   for (j = i + 1; j < givenArray.length; j++) {
//     if (givenArray[i] + givenArray[j] == desiredSum) {
//       flag = 1;
//       console.log(givenArray[i] + " & " + givenArray[j]);
//     }
//   }
// }

// generate all possible sums from desiredSum and check if both of required numbers are available


for (i = 0; i < givenArray; i++) {
    if (givenArray.includes(i) && givenArray.includes(desiredSum-i)) {
        console.log((desiredSum-x) + ' & ' + (x))
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you just need one pair of numbers that adds up to equal the sum or all pairs? See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64858771/5648954) for more ideas

Comment: What is your actual question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `desiredSum - x` and `x` approach is actually done via a `cache` mechanism. As you iterate over your array, you check for the difference of current element from the `desiredSum` and if present in `cache`, add it to the `output` array. Else you would store the current number in the `cache`.

Time complexity - O(n)

Space complexity - O(n)

```js
let givenArray = [1, 2, 5, 4, 4,3];
let desiredSum = 7;



function twoSum(desiredSum,givenArray){
let output = [];
let cache = new Set();
for (let i = 0; i < givenArray.length; i++) {
  const firstNumber = givenArray[i];
  const secondNumber = desiredSum - firstNumber;
  if(cache.has(secondNumber)){
   output.push([firstNumber,secondNumber]);
  }
  else{
  cache.add(firstNumber);
  }
}
return output;
}

const result = twoSum(desiredSum,givenArray);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const set = new Set();

for (var x in givenArray) {
    if (set.has(desiredSum-x)) {
        console.log((desiredSum-x) + ' & ' + (givenArray[x]));
        break;
    }
    set.add(givenArray[x]);
}
```

This is an O(n) time O(n) space solution

Comment: brijeshwawdhane@brijeshs-MacBook-Pro % node test.js
/Users/brijeshwawdhane/Desktop/files/test.js:32
forEach (x in givenArray) {
                          ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'

Comment: @Brijesh I did not run the code in an editor. There were basic typos. The logic is correct.